# Running a script over Telnet in Python

Tags: python, server, telnet

so I have some normal Python scripts that you can access through your terminal normally. Like the script works with your terminal (it is a game).

Now I want to somehow make a script that creates a telnet server, and when a user telnet's to the ip, the script will run in their terminal.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/miniboa. This is small and light telnet server for python. But I'm not sure I understood everything. You want to copy script over telnet from the server to the client ip?

Comment: @Laszlowaty: I'll take a look at that soon. I basically want a script that creates a telnet server, and when some user connects to that telnet server, it will run another python script that's hosted on the same machine as the telnet server. Basically allowing them to access the script I'm using over telnet.

Comment: Well, it's fairy easy. In the server just read the user input and then `if` input is correct just use os.system('command') to run your script and catch stdout and send it to the user. But this is a bit of security issue (don't let write any command), just the one that is allowed.

Comment: Can you write an example as the answer to this question, please? Still having trouble understanding...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xinetd** to add a service starting your python script. The standard input and output will be transmitted over the network on desired port, so you do not need to modify your scripts (`input`/`raw_input` and `print` methods will work fine).

Brief tutorial:
http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-add-custom-new-service-under.html

Answer (score 0):

I won't create whole code for this problem. I will just give you a brief example.

This is the part of the `telnet server`:

```
list_of_the_connections = []
for connection in list_of_the_connections:
    user_command = connection.read()
    if user_command = 'name_of_the_script':
        stdout = catch_stdout(os.system('python name_of_the_script'))
    connection.send(stdout)
```

Line `stdout = catch_stdout(os.system('python name_of_the_script'))` is using `os.system` to run the bash command and function `catch_stdout` catches the output of that command. Later on, all you have to do is to send this output to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved by calling the program that I was trying to connect to over telnet in a [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) spawn class and the telnet project [miniboa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/miniboa). By wrapping the program in pexpect you can the read and write to stdin/stdout safely.

To use the input function, pexpect uses regular expressions to know when to stop reading and get input, so I added '>' to the end of my read from stdin function.

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.process = pexpect.spawnu(PROGRAM)

def on_connect(client):
    clients.append(Client(client))

def process_clients():
    """
    Check each client, if client.cmd_ready == True then there is a line of
    input available via client.get_command().
    """
    for client in clients:
        if client.active and client.cmd_ready:
            # If the client sends input echo it to the chat room
            interact(client)

def interact(client):
    choice = client.process.expect([re.compile('\n*/>$'), '\n'])
    if choice == 1: # not an input prompt
        if len(client.process.before) == 0:
            return
        client.client.send(client.process.before+'\n')
    else: #input
        msg = client.client.get_command().strip()
        client.process.sendline(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tn = miniboa.TelnetServer(
        port=7000, 
        address='127.0.0.1', 
        on_connect = on_connect
    )
    while True:
        tn.poll()
        if len(clients) > 0:
            process_clients()
```

PROGRAM is the program to be called. This is mostly gleaned from the [miniboa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/miniboa) examples.